# Number of multiples of x in a range for large numbers

Tags: java, math, division

This is simple mathematics I guess, but I just can't figure it out + I'm new to coding. I need to find out how many numbers are divisible by x in a range. Here's an example: I need to find how many numbers in the range 11 to 30 are divisible by 3. The answer is 7, and I already coded it:

```
while (a <= b) {
    if (a % 3 == 0) {
        c++;
        a++;
    else {
        a++;
    }
}
```

HOWEVER, this works horribly for large numbers as I check every single number. I tried doing `c = (b-a)/3`, but obviously this doesn't work for all examples, just like it doesn't for the one above. So, could you please help me find some sort of a simple equation that would calculate this for me. I'm feeling so stupid for not being able to figure this one out.

Comment: What's the programming language?

Comment: _“I need to find out how many numbers are divisable by x in a range”_ – sounds like a classic homework assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In psudo-code:

1. Calculate the smallest number divisible by 3 that is bigger than
   `a`: `c = math.ceil(a / 3) * 3`.
2. Calculate the biggest number divisible by 3 that is smaller than
   `b`: `d = math.floor(b / 3) * 3`.
3. The answer is `(d - c) / 3 + 1`.

In the example of `11` to `30`, `c` is `12`, and `d` is `30`, the final answer is `7`.

Answer (score 0):

You're close! Do something like (no idea what you're coding in so this will be pseudo-code):

```
function numDiv(int a, int b, int divBy) {
int x;
if(a>b) x=1+a-b;
else x=1+b-a;
return floor(x/divBy);
}
```

the floor and +1 will should get you there.